# Access Session in Asp.NET Web API in Mono

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, asp.net-web-api, mono

I've a complex list of permissions stored in the user's session object. I'm accessing this in my custom implementation of the `AuthorizeAttribute` to manage access to my REST API.

In order to make it work, I had to enable the SessionState for API Controllers (by default it wouldn't be loaded). This did the trick:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
{
  if (IsWebApiRequest())
  {
    HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(
      System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Required);
  }
}

private static bool IsWebApiRequest()
{
  return HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.StartsWith(@"~/api");
}
```

It works now fine in VisualStudio during development, but when I deploy it to mono the `Session` object is again null.

Any idea how I can force Mono to load the Sessions also for API Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems like it doesn't work. There is a bug from 2012:

> [SessionStateBehaviour in HttpContext is ignored](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3012)

and there are also other bugs with sessions in asp.net mono: [Memory leak in asp.net with sessions enabled](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=381)

I've instead [switched from the Session to a Dictionary for caching](http://peter.grman.at/request-authorization-in-asp.net-web-api-in-mono/).